# How to transfer a driver from installer to OS

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I have just installed ubuntu server 20.04, and I find it strange that the installer instantly recognizes the driver, but the OS does not at all. I have tried installing every driver I could find, to no avail. I have a Realtek RTL8111E on my motherboard, and as I said, the installer recognized the ethernet controller just fine, but the installed OS doesn't. Is there a way I can transfer the driver from the installer to the OS?
Please answer soon!

EDIT: the suggestion by @waltinator ([My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)) does not apply because that is for WiFi, my server driver is only ethernet.

Specs: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Gigabyte GA-H67MA-USB3-B3 for the motherboard, Realtek RTL8111E ethernet controller chip, initrd.img-5.4.0-155-generic for the image.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Apologies, for not formatting correctly. The post has been edited to include the specs.